# JPA EclipseLink Weaver generates call to porperty getter inside its setter -> NullPointerException

Tags: jpa, orm, glassfish, eclipselink, embeddable

I have an `@Embeddable` class that uses property access to wrap another object that's not directly mappable by JPA via field access. It looks like this:

```
@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class MyWrapper {

    @NotNull
    @Transient
    private WrappedType wrappedField;

    protected MyWrapper() {
    }

    public MyWrapper(WrappedType wrappedField) {
        this.wrappedField = wrappedField;
    }

    @Transient
    public WrappedType getWrappedField() {
        return wrappedField;
    }

    public void setWrappedField(WrappedType wrappedField) {
        this.wrappedField = wrappedField;
    }

    @Column(name = "wrappedTypeColumn")
    protected String getJPARepresentation() {
        return wrappedField.toString();
    }

    protected void setJPARepresentation(String jpaRepresentation) {
        wrappedField = new WrappedType(jpaRepresentation);
    }
}
```

Persisting an `@Entity` with a `MyWrapper` field works fine. But when I execute a query to load the Entity from the database, I get a `NullPointerException`. The stacktrace and some debugging shows that Eclipselink creates a new instance of `MyWrapper` by calling its default constructor and then calls the `setJPARepresentation()` method (as expected).

But now the unexpected happens: the stacktrace shows that the `getJPARepresentation()` is called from inside the setter, which then of course leads to a `NullPointerException` when return `wrappedField.toString()` is executed.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyWrapper.getJPARepresentation(MyWrapper.java:27)
    at MyWrapper.setJPARepresentation(MyWrapper.java)
    ... 109 more
```

Fact is, there is obviously no call to the getter in the code and the stacktrace shows no line number indicating from where in the setter called the getter. So my conclusion would be, that the bytecode weaver of Eclipselink generated the call to the getter.

It's easy to build a workaround, but **my question is: Why does Eclipselink do that?**

P.S: I'm using EclipseLink 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461 in a GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2 (build 23)

Answer (score 0):

When weaving is enabled (default on Glassfish), EclipseLink will weave code into property get/set methods for,

- change tracking
- fetch groups (partial objects)
- lazy (relationships)

For change tracking support the set method will be weaved to check if the new value is different than the old value, so it must call the get method to get the old value.

Now this is still odd, as since your are building a new object, I would not expect the change listener to be set yet, so would expect the change tracking check to be bypassed.  You could decompile the code to see exactly what was generated.

The easiest fix is to just put in a null check in your get method, which is probably best in general for your code.  You could also switch to field access, which will not have issues with side-affects in get/set methods.  You could also use a Converter to handle the conversion, instead of doing the conversion in get/set methods.

Comment: Field access can't be used because JPA has no native support to map `MyWrapper`and I can't use Converters I'm not allowed to use provider dependent mechanisms as the code has to run with OpenJPA too.